# Looking for a project similar to UN CartoTile

Tags: data-request, geospatial

I am looking for **map data** (geojson) that is **similar in style to the UN CartoTile** style of map found here: https://www.un.org/geospatial/mapsgeo/webservices.
I found a site some time back that has this data but I am unable to find it again.  That is, the site has data that will render a simplified, blocky style administrative regions on a map.

**If** I am recalling correctly the site was for a fairly recent project, open source, and was from a pretty well known organization. On the home page there was a graphic showing the blocky administrative regions of Europe I think. I believe with a purplish color.

It definitely is not the UN site but here is a screen capture from the link above for reference.

[image]

It was recommended that I ask here. See: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/381068/1238100.